# How to add Custom Validation for checking Email is already exist or not for Not Required field in angular 4 reactive forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Reactive form.I want to check whether email id is exist or not using rest call. I have use following code

```
emailValidator(control : FormControl)
  {
const q = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.signupService.isEmaiIDExist(control.value)
        .pipe(catchError(this.signupService.errorHandler))
        .subscribe(res => {console.log(res)
          if(res.status==400)
          {
             resolve(null) 
          }else
          {
           resolve({ 'isEmailExist': true })
          }
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
    return q;
}
```

And in formbuilder group

```
userEmail: new FormControl(null,[Validators.pattern('.+\@.+\..+')]),this.emailValidator.bind(this))
```

I **don't** want to make this field **Required**.if i make it Required then above code is working fine .But if i removed required field then while component loading it directly sends 3 rest calls to backend without entering any value in formcontrol field.
So how to solve this issue..Please help.Thank you in advance

Comment: Here you can just add the condition and check is email field is empty then return before validator rest call.

Comment: i have tried this but giving errors..if i enter something and clear the input then it directly sends rest call. i want check if exist or not and  show error message in mat error field(i am using material). suggest if any other method or technique to do this working